Sort by time from 7am to 6:59am
I would like to find a macro to sort time in a column but having sorted from 7am to 6:59am instead of the original sorting Time from 00:00 to 11:59pm
Thank you for your help
Sub Macro2()
 TRI Macro

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Arr").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Arr").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "G2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Arr").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub


Maybe add a helper column with a formula and sort on that?

Include the date along with the time. (You can format to show only the time). And then just set your range to include only those times from today at 7 AM until tomorrow at 6:59 AM

Or add a helper column with a formula =MOD(G2-"7:0",1) and sort on this helper column.
